# Uploading array into firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to upload a large array into firestore, so each object will go in its own document:

```
qtable.forEach(function(obj) {
db.collection("menu").add({
        id: obj.q,
        name: obj.q,
        description: obj.q,
        price: obj.q,
        type: obj.q
}).then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
return null;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
```

I did npm install firestore and have all these requires:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
```

But it seems to do nothing at all.  Nothing is being uploaded.

Comment: How are you running this code?  Please edit the question to include enough information that anyone could reproduce the issue.

Comment: Your code looks fine (although not sure why are you including Firestore separately when you already have admin sdk). What happens when you run? No errors? No data gets inserted?

Comment: Also just for fun, confirm that qtable actually has objects? Put some kinda debug in the loop just to confirm you have data in there?

Comment: Thanks, it works now -- the problem was I had a return fetch right below this code, and it was returning another promise which ended the function -- after removing that return fetch this worked now.